# How to do nested dynamodb calls in lambda nodejs?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've been having problems with calling async/await functions and returning that data for another function.

How would you write a lambda nodejs file, that:

A. Calls externalFile.js and await a return response with a value. (Calls the dynamodb and asks how many items it has, returns 10)

B. Once 10 is returned the main function passes 10 into another dynamodb call, to query number 10.

Or

C. ExternalFile2.js is called that async/awaits a response and then something is executed with that response.

Basically the idea is, I want to return the length of my table, then query the table, then update the table, all within an async order so that the data is available from the first call.

How would you handle this?

My function returns null and never executes any console.logs dynamodb calls

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");
let totalMade = null;
let dbTotal = null;
let contractInfo = {};
var getTotalMade = require('./web3.js')

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

async function get() {
    try {
        totalMade = await getTotalMade.data.methods.getTotal();
       console.log(totalMade)
        return totalMade.total
    }
    catch(error) {
        return error;
    }
}


    
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-2" });
//Check External Contract for totalMade result
let tokenAddress = "0x32659521996926TEST"
let totalSupply = get().then(res => console.log("index results : "+ res))
console.log(" This is my results: this is the get(): " + totalSupply);

//Gets results from totalSupply and console logs properly, but cannot call dynamodb. Nothing executes

  //call DB with totalMade as an argument 
   var params = {
       TableName: "XYZ123"
   }
    dynamodb.describeTable(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
          return err
        } else {
            
               if(ID > data.Table.ItemCount){
                console.log(ID, data.Table.ItemCount)
         
                  dbTotal = data.Table.ItemCount;
                  console.log("end of fetch: " + dbTotal + " and the SC total: " + ID)

                  var docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();
                  contractInfo.allCards.forEach(item1 => {
                      console.log("running loop: " + item1)
                     docClient.putItem({
                    TableName: 'XYZ123',
                    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(item1)',
                               Item: {
    'cardID' : item1,
    'numberID' : dbTotal++ ,
  }

                  }).promise()
                  .then((err, res) => {
                      if(err)console.log(err)
                      if(res) {

                        callback(null, {
                statusCode: '200',
                body: {
                res
                }
            });      }            
                  })
                  })
                 
                                 
               }
               if(ID <= data.Table.ItemCount){
                 callback(null, {
                statusCode: '500',
                body: {
                  uptoDate: true
                }
            });                  
           }
        

     }

 
 
  

  
}).catch(err  => {
  console.log(err)
})

};
```

My external file that index.js is calling:

```
     var tokenGen = require('./ERC721Generator.json');
    var ERC721a = require('./ERC721Token.json');
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/API_KEY"));
    var version = web3.version.api; 
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const tokenGenerator = contract(tokenGen);
    const ERC721 = contract(ERC721a);
    
    async function getItem(item){
       // Return new promise 
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          // Do async job
           token.tokensArray().call(item, function(err, resp) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(resp));
                }
            })
        })
    
    }
    var methods = {
      getTotal: async function() {
    
       tokenGenerator.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
       ERC721.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
     let contractInfo = {};  
    
    let token = await tokenGenerator.at("0xdf3d2033651212771a4f25d27d307e9f76de50b9")



//Can get this far, but nothing else runs after this
//Never gets into the while loop, why??



    let i = 0;
    contractInfo.total = await token.totalGenerated.call()
    while( i < contractInfo.total){
      getItem(i).then((err, res) => {
          contractInfo.allCards.push(res);
          console.log("inside loop" + contractInfo.allCards)
          i++
        })
      }
    
    return contractInfo
    }
      
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    exports.data = {
      methods
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: I've added some code @Boney

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
export default async (event, context, callback) => {
   [err,data ] = await promiseToObject(dynamoClient.put(params).promise())

   if(err) {
     //handle err
     callback(err, null)

   }

  // results.Items has the returned data


  // do another await!

}

function promiseToObject(promise) {
    return promise.then((data) => {
        return [null, data]
    }).catch(err => [err])
}
```

If this isn't clear then I'll update, but basically you can sequentially process data using await, you don't need callbacks, then etc!

Please note PromiseToObject is not my code I'll provide a citation asap!

If you want to abstract the dynamo calls into another script you just need to return the promise from the dynamoDB call then you can await it.

Comment: decople the code so that each dynamodb has its own invocation. make sure you have an asynx handler and all the functions are async.  you could do something like

Answer (score 0):

use this functions

```
async function getSingleData(params) {
  return dynamoDB.get(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return response.Item;
  })
}
```

**Call function example**

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'user',
  Key: { userId: driverId }
};
 
var data = await getSingleData(params)
```

**Multiple data function**

```
async function getMultipleData(params) {
  return dynamoDB.scan(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return response.Items;
  })
}
```

**Call function example**

```
const paramss = {
  "TableName": "order",
  "ScanIndexForward": true,
  "FilterExpression": "#DYNOBASE_fromcity = :fromcity",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#DYNOBASE_fromcity": "fromcity"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":fromcity": cities[i]
  }
};


var result = await getMultipleData(paramss)
```